# Using grep-awk and sed in one-row-command result in a "No such file or directory" error

Tags: awk, grep

..And I know why:

I have a xml document with lots of information inside. I need to extract what I need and eventually print them on a new file.

The xml (well, part of it.. rows just keeps repeating)

```
<module classname="org.openas2.processor.receiver.AS2DirectoryPollingModule"
    outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toMartha/"
    errordir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toMartha/error"
    sentdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/data/Sent/Martha"
    interval="600"
    defaults="sender.name=me_myself, receiver.name=Martha"
    sendfilename="true"
    mimetype="application/standard"/>

<module classname="org.openas2.processor.receiver.AS2DirectoryPollingModule"
    outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toJosh/"
    errordir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toJosh/error"
    sentdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/data/Sent/Josh"
    interval="600"
    defaults="sender.name=me_myself, receiver.name=Josh"
    sendfilename="true"
    mimetype="application/standard"/>

<module classname="org.openas2.processor.receiver.AS2DirectoryPollingModule"
    outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toPamela/"
    errordir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toPamela/error"
    interval="600"
    defaults="sender.name=me_myself, receiver.name=Pamela"
    sendfilename="true"
    mimetype="application/standard"/>
```

I need to extract the folder after "Outbound" and clean it from quotes or slashes.
Also, I need to exclude the "/error" so I get only 1 result for each of them.

My command is:

```
grep -o -v "/error" "Outbound/" config.xml | awk -F"Outbound/" '{print $2}' | sed -e "s/\/\"//g" > /tmp/sync_users
```

The error is: `grep: Outbound/: No such file or directory` which of course means that I'm giving to grep too many arguments (?) - If i remove the `-v "/error"` it would work but would print also the names with "/error".

Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**
As some pointed out in their example (thanks for the time you put in), I'd need to extract these words based on the sample above:

```
toMartha
toJosh
toPamela
```

Comment: I so LOVE when someone downvotes posts. You know what I like the most? When I get no reason for that.

Comment: `grep` expects `"Outbound/"` to be the filename from which you search. What is your expected output?

Comment: true, that's why if i remove the -v "error", the outbound become the argument to search and the config.xml the file. I need a way to exlude a word which is not by using the -v of grep (found with sed)

Comment: This is what happens when you don't give us a real sample of the data. We are taking shots in the dark and everybodys' time is lost. No wonder someone downvoted.

Comment: excuse me? THIS is a real example of data. I don't bother writing 700+ line of xml. I only need to extract that word(s) from that sentence(s). I'm sorry to waste your time, I'm just asking to experts because I am not

Comment: As you want to know why: excerpt: "And I know why", and then "I'm giving to grep too many arguments (?)" sounds like you didn't even read the man page. When I did vote down there was no sample output. The real question is nearly hidden between sample input and the try and doesn't really explain what you're after (cleaning slashes in a directory makes no sense). The tittle has nothing to do with the error, I didn't try to edit as this Q fall into the "unsalvageable" category => Not useful, downvote. Not closed as reasonably scoped and answerable anyway, but still a bad question in my opinion.

Comment: I search on Google the words "grep" and “No such file or directory”. This post will appear. The user will read that it is caused by the argument passed to grep. HE will read how to improve his grep with awk thanks to the answer users will write. It is for my case or for anyone else.
Your opinion count nothing to me. It is good manner to explain&do rather than do.

Comment: @Nihvel FWIW I did add an answer, forgot to click send before lunch. And for explain & do, considering the amount of badly written posts, I do as I'm pleased to explain or not. I do hope you understand at least part of what I said above. Someone coming for a grep problem an reading your post may really have a hard time telling if it's applicable to his/her case

Comment: I appreciate it anyway, thank you for that sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give grep multiples patterns they have to be separated by newlines or specified by multiples pattern option (-e,  F,..  ). However -v invert the match as a whole,  you can't invert only one.

For what you're after you can use PCRE (-P argument) for the lookaround ability:

`grep -o -P '(?<=Outbound\/)[^\/]+(?!.*\/error)' config.xml`

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YCs2dU/2)

The regex try to

- match something not a slash at least once, the `[^\/]+`
- preceded by `Outbound/` the positive lookbehind `(?<=Outbound\/)`
- and not followed by something ending with `/error`, the negative lookahead `(?!.*\/error)`

With your first sample input:

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<=Outbound\/)[^\/]+(?!.*\/error)' test.txt
toMartha
toJosh
toPamela
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I face same errors I had before where words with /error are not excluded but just printed without /error and without the last letter:

toMartha toMarth toJosh toJos toPamela to Pamel

Comment: @Nihvel which version of grep are you using ? I saw something about a ubuntu 14.04 box and copying from windows, so maybe a `fromdos ` of your file could help (but it should not be a problem with this regex). (I get the proper result as shown above even with the new input you added to you question)

Comment: Using the 2.16 version (not able to update I'm sorry). Yes a Ubuntu (i don't like ubuntu..but...) 14.03. I ssh to it from windows and I try to be careful with LF-CR

Comment: @Nihvel just tested with your actual sample on grep 2.16, with CRLF line ending (windows) and it works as expected...

Comment: I just read your comment on CRLF i didn't see before! im trying again and post result

Comment: @Nihvel sorry, just saw I did a copy/paste mistake on first command line, a `.*`was missing.

Comment: yeah that worked! it is correct now! This answer is cleaner than the one currently chosen, thinking about switching to this!
How should I move, if I wish to add some other filter? Can I keep the format of "`+(filter_here) `" - I just noticed one of the 40+ name's got a quote sign instead of /". And this cause the output to have `toMartha [...] toBrian"`

Comment: Which character is the quote sign ? :`"` or `'` or another ?

Comment: it is this `"` - `outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toBrian"`

Comment: @Nihvel in this case I would add the `"` to the characters to not take so `[^\/]+` become `[^\/"]+` I assume this user doesn't have an error directory anyway. `[]` denotes a character class, starting it with a `^` negate it. You can give a try modifying the regex in the link provided in the answer, and the explanation for it is on the right panel.

Comment: Correct, all the users have the error directory but in this script I only need the user name once. And your fix on the `"` worked really good! I appreciate your help and your explanation, on this and the main post, thanks sir!

Comment: @Tensibai - it is worth noting that `grep` accepts multiple patterns using the `-e`/`--regexp` option. See my answer below.

Comment: @yuval I'm against piping when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Tensibai regardless, I think it's best to modify the opening sentence of your answer as `grep` does allow more than a single pattern.

Comment: @yuval I'd like to confirm for which version it is true before editing

Comment: @Tensibai POSIX grep: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

Comment: @Yuval done, feel free to edit to add this link and keep the credit for it.

Answer (score 3):

could be intersting to use **sed** in this case

```
sed -e '\#/Outbound/#!d' -e '\#/error"$#d' -e 's#.*/Outbound/##;s#/\{0,1\}"$##' Config.xml
```

**awk** version, assuming  (for last print) that your line is always 1 folder below Outbound as shown

```
awk -F '/' '$0 !~ /\/Outbound\// || /\/error"$/ {next} {print $(NF-1)}' Config.xml
```

Comment: Both the commands return both toPamela/" and toPamela/error/" thanks for trying of course! really appreciate it

Comment: except for the awk one, that prints without the /"

Comment: could you sho a bit more of the original XML and on which system are you using that. i copy your sample to my linux and output is what expected here. First sed cannot return *Pamela/error* due to `-e '\#/error"$#d'` deleting normaly this line.

Comment: sure, be updating in a while! I am working on your awk anyway, i was able to get rid of /" but words are repeated (meant as the one with /error is not exluded)

Comment: are you on MAC or PC via cygwin ? I just test with your new data sample also on an AIX and works as expected in both case.

Comment: it is a ubuntu 14.03 server, im ssh to it from windows (but this does not matter).
After break i'll be trying again but i found the solution already. still i like your command and im going to upvote ur job, and be trying once more in a while

Answer (score 2):

Loose the `grep` altogether:

```
$ awk '/outboxdir/{gsub(/^.+Outbound\/|\/" *\r?$/,""); print}' file
toMartha
toJosh
toPamela
```

- <s>`/^outboxdir/`</s> `/outboxdir/`only process records that have  <s>start with</s> `outboxdir` on them
- `gsub` remove unwanted parts of the record
- added space removal at the end of record and CRLF fix for Windows originated files

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried but nothing is printed unluckily

Comment: great you are getting closer! I was too editing it to "not start with outboxdir" but that contain it.
Still, result is toMartha/" toJosh/" [lots of space in last row] outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba7user/Outbound/toPamela/"

Comment: assume maybe that line with *outboxdir* are only those with *Outbound* like show in sample but not state in OP info

Comment: Problem is probably the space in the data that isn't in the sample: _It is ... and more space between the words_. Solution is not prepared for it as I can't match what I can't see. In the end of record I remove `/"`. If there is a single space, the string won't get removed and you have `toMartha/"` etc.

Comment: yes correct, outboxdir and outbound are only seen in their row. I could base the search on one or another, does not matter which one

Comment: @JamesBrown sir you're helping me a lot, i thank you for that! i'm just sorry i probably am not able to give every info one would need? The xml file is formatted as a xml file, sure it contains spaces and words are not all in line. I guess this should not matter. Who would care where a word positioned in the document?  If it is part of a row, it is a row. I am probably wrong.. but.. Anyway, the error is the one reported previously, i too am working on it but can't yet have solution

Comment: if it may be of interest, i used to "grep -o" to print my search excluding everything else that grep would not highlight. In this case, it does not matter where the word starts, it would just show and print on a new line

Comment: Are you on Windows? I added `\r` removal to the record tail handling regex.

Comment: The server is a Ubuntu 14.03

Comment: Please try it now?

Comment: Wonderful! the "/error" is gone and all is clean. Though I can not yet explain why the last result (Pamela) is printed shifted and with whole path "outboxdir="%home%/../../../home/samba/user/Outbound/toPamela" BUT without the /"

Comment: Error in the sample, Outbond and not Outbound. Thank you sir!! it is solved

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
grep -i "outbound" your_file | awk -F"Outbound/" '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/error//' -e 's/\/\"//' | uniq
```

Should work :)

Comment: So far this solution really worked! Going to be the marked one! It is "bash ugly" but it works great!

Comment: My XML is so huge, and I found out that it is true that this command removes the  /error but it doesn't exclude the string itself.
Result is:
toMartha
toMartha
toJosh
toJosh
toPamela
toPamela

How would you fix this? thanks anyway - EDIT sorry for now I remove the marked sign on it, it almost solve my problem

Comment: No problem :) I guess a simple uniq command in the end would work. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` in `gawk`and capturing group in regex

```
awk 'match($0, /^.*\/Outbound\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]*)\/?"$/, a){
    if(a[2]!="error"){print a[1]}
}' config.xml
```

you get,

```
toMartha
toJosh
toPamela
```

Comment: I honestly would have never ever arrived to such command! Looks impressive. I tried it and forwarded the output to a file but the file is empty. So i tried exactly as you typed (and activated the  set -x ) but nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can accept multiple patterns with the `-e` option (aka `--regexp`, even though it can be used with `--fixed-strings` too, go figure). However, `-v` (`--invert-match`) applies to all of the patterns as a group.

Another solution would be to chain two calls to `grep`:

```
grep -v "/error" config.xml | grep "Outbound/" | awk -F"Outbound/" '{print $2}' | sed -e "s/\/\"//g"
```

Comment: Your second grep can be omitted by adding a /Outbound/ before the print block in awkward,  it avoid at least one fork from the shell.  Sed can probably be avoided with a Field separator using an alternation in the -F regex.  But as grep can do all of this itself with the correct regex that's better to aVoid piping altogether

Comment: Yes, granted there are simpler solutions. Just thought it's best to have all options laid out. However, why avoid piping? Separating tasks between processes can actually benefit performance on any machine with more than a single core.

Comment: There's no gain when tasks are sequential, there's less loss of time but as task A must have process the line before task B,  you still have two 'read' first  the file, the second on stdin, you just multiply calls to fgetc. That's harmless under billions lines but the overhead can become visible on very large files. I think every task this way when they are not 'one shot',  and as such I do the same on SO answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the update Yuval . Although I still find the answer given by @Tensibai simpler and shorter. And for me working with the laptop and a tiny monitor, I'd always go for less code with same result. Anyway, the script is in production already and I am not going to edit it, but I appreciate your answer ;)